# Rails see what apps a user has installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering - is there any way when a user on a mobile site visits a Rails site to check to see what apps that user has installed on their phone?

A client is looking for an additional way to verify that a user actually meets the demographic info they enter in (so if they have SnapChat/Instagram installed, they might be in the 14-30 range, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, it's not possible. That would mean any website can understand my habits and inspect my phone configuration.

As far as I know, both Android and iOS don't expose such information via web.

Comment: I figured. Good for me, bad for the client though :)